# WINE Apps in fullscreen

Tags: 14.04, wine, resolution, screen

I am having a problem when running old games through WINE

The problem is that most old games have a maximum resolution that is much smaller than mine (1366x768) and instead of being stretched to cover the full screen it only covers the top-left part of it.

For example when I run StarCraft it will cover exactly 800x600 starting from the top-left of the screen, and the rest is all black.

I have this problem with modern games as well but for those I can set the resolution to exactly what I need and the problem is solved

Also, I tried running the game 'FATE' on Lubuntu x86 on another computer and it worked correctly on all availabile resolutions... it seems this only occurs for Ubuntu x64, maybe because of Unity or something?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 x64
I use the latest proprietary Nvidia drivers

EDIT: I am also having another problem that may or may not be related. Sometimes when exiting games that are not on the native resolution, all opened windowses, and even the context menu, get a big black border around them that won't dissapear unless I log off and back on, or reboot, or simply just restarting Unity through the terminal. This border will appear when I open oher things too

Comment: If you set wine to "Emulate a virtual desktop, in the graphics tab, then it might be able to achieve a higher res.

Comment: Already tried it and I still have the same problem. I can confirm that the app did indeed launch in a virtual desktop since I was able to see the "virtual desktop" for a fraction of a second after closing the game.

Comment: What if you open another app first? What is the desktop set to?

Comment: Ok so I started a windowed app in an 1024x768 desktop (it was windowed). All went fine so far but when I started Starcraft the desktop went to 800x600 (Starcraft's resolution) and stayed that way until I closed Starcraft and then it went back to normal and the first app was still there...

Comment: That is strange... what does winehq say about starcraft? edit: It says it should work fine :/

Comment: Yes, everyone says it works perfectly but I also have this problem in other games too not just Starcraft... After searching a little more on Google I found out something about resolutions not being set correctly in xorg.conf but I don't know anything about this file or how to fix it... :-s

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem... I just switched to the integrated Intel Card from nVidia X Server Settings using PRIME Profiles and it works fine using this card... when I switch back to nVidia I get the issue back as well... Also, while I'm on nVidia I can't use xrandr to change the resolution through the terminal, but on Intel it works... however setting it manually from System Settings/Display works on both

Answer (score 1):

I use `xrandr` to scale the game.
After the game is up I have a custom key linked to this command;

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1360x768 --scale 0.59x0.78 --panning 800x600
```

When you need to return to the normal size screen;

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1360x768 --scale 1x1 --panning 1360x768
```

`VGA-0` is the name of my display, use `xrandr` from terminal to find the name of your display.  Old games are a real challenge when they never made the game window to resize.